# How do you know all the exceptions a method can throw

Tags: java, exception, exception-safe, exception-safety

Is there a way to get some details regarding exception safety aspects of Java's standard classes? Mainly working with C++ and C#, I'm confused with Java exception specifications, so I need to understand the proper way of working with exceptions.

To be more specific, let's consider `ServerSocket`. It starts listening for incoming connections as soon as its object is constructed. Then, you should use `accept()` to accept the connection (if someone tries to connect).

In case you've previously configured your server socket with `setSoTimeout()`, there's a change that `accept()` will throw `SocketTimeoutException` because nobody tried to connect in a specified period of time. That's fine, server socket is still usable, so you just call `accept()` once again.

But `SocketTimeoutException` is not the only thing that `accept()` may throw. What does all the other exceptions mean? If I wrap call to `accept()` with 2 catch clauses: for `SocketTimeoutException` and `IOException`, can I still *safely* use the related `ServerSocket` instance after I got into `IOException` clause?

I'd really appreciate both Java-wide and ServerSocket-specific answers.

Comment: you'd have to dig into the javadocs to see what all of the other exceptions mean.  something well documented would explain what's going on.  Java-wide, there's no answer.  The object still exists after the exception occurs, but what *state* that object is in depends on the implementation of that specific thing.

Comment: @John Gardner: have already spent too much time reading docs. No explicit answers. What does the "I/O error occurred" stand for? Does it mean my LAN card's dead or is it just a network lag for a couple of seconds? While the first one is critical, the second one is not so obvious to be "unrecoverable".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not safe to reuse the object. For such a question I would always look into a source, that is the reason it is open.

So if you look into that one: http://kickjava.com/src/java/net/ServerSocket.java.htm you notice that in `accept()` a SocketException (inherits from IOException) is thrown if the socket is closed or not bound anymore. Both states indicate that the ServerSocket is not valid anymore.

So for this class, generally, if you fail with an exception, always try to gracefully close the ServerSocket in a finally block and then recreate it.

Additionally on your Java-wide question scope: Always look into the source and understand what the interface is doing. If it is mission-critical write tests that reproduce the behaviour (should not be easy at all with such a low-level api).

Finally - is Java consistently doing such things that way? No. Some classes are stateless, others are not (like ServerSocket), some are thread-safe, others not. And you need to understand - either from the documentation or (mostly) from the code - what state they build in order to understand what to do when an Exception knocks you off from the main path.

Most people curse those checked Java exceptions, because most of them (as with most of the IOExceptions) are not really recoverable in a meaningful way. Most of the time, they argue, you cannot understand each and every fine corner case. Which is the reason why many complex frameworks may retry twice or thrice if they think in this case they might, but finally throw a RuntimeException to a top framework layer. There  they make something useful out of it (a meaningful error providing context) and log all the details they have, which is a huge stack trace most of the time. A great resource of knowledge, feared by many developers.

So what can you do if you could not recover from an untested corner-case problem? Throw up (probably with a some subclass of RuntimeException) the most meaningful stacktrace annotated with all the context you have. Setup monitoring. And if you run into a frequent problem, fix it.

Comment: Why look into to the source when the javadoc is available and clear ?

Comment: Javadoc on ServerSocket for example does not tell you, if and how to recover and which kinds of IOExceptions can happen. But from my perspective it is necessary to know something about the device details and how to handle them if I am using a device. In my company we keep saying: It is all documented in the code :-)

Comment: IOException occurs mostly when a read/write on a device fails. For my point of view, I don't see the need to have information about the device

Comment: The documentation on ServerSocket exceptions is woefully inadequate in actually determining what the actually error condition actually is. Source code and stacktraces are about the only learning tools for dealing with them.

Comment: @Perception - there's a good reason why the javadoc for I/O exceptions thrown is vague (in general, and in this specific case).  If it was specific, it would create an expectation that Java could distinguish the different cases across all implementation platforms.  In reality it can't, because the information needed to do this is often not available from the syscall ABIs.

Comment: @Stephen C - You're quite possibly right about that. The fact remains though, that reading the Javadoc for ServerSocket is sufficient to tell you the types of exceptions that occur, but don't really give insight as the *reason* why they occur. Which is what the OP is curious about.

Comment: @Perception he *is* right about that. The underlying issue is that the Berkeley Sockets API itself is rather under-specified. You really have to know TCP pretty well at the protocol level to understand its behaviour in any high level API.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. The object still exists - May be in an error state in which case it will throw other exceptions until that is rectified.

Comment: So, in generic case, there's no way to tell whether the object is OK or not after calling one of its methods caused an exception?

Comment: this doesn't really answer the question

Comment: it doesn't really answer the question because it isn't really answerable.  It depends on the exception!

Comment: @John Gardner: the question is - depending on exception, how do I know?

Answer (score 1):

If you read the specification for [ServerSocket](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/ServerSocket.html#accept%28%29), you will see that it throws an IOException "if an I/O error occurs when waiting for a connection." Is it safe to `accept()` on the socket again? Yes. Are you going to get the same Exception thrown again? Likely so.

Comment: Do you mean, that `accept()` is just a guy who tells there are problems, but in fact, it's not a guy who really fails?

Comment: What do you mean by 'fails'? It will attempt to make a connection. If it cannot, it will throw one of the 4 exceptions to tell you what happened. In this case, IOException is a catchall (as it often is). If one of the other 3 exceptions does not explain the problem, it gets thrown.

Comment: ServerSocket has a queue of clients who want to connect. A call to `accept()` takes the first one out of this queue and tries to establish the connection. Somewhere in the middle of this operation, client ISP go down, so we've failed to establish the connection with this client. Does it affect other clients in the queue? Will `accept()` work for the next client?

Comment: Nope, It wont affect other clients in the queue. accept in this case will work because every connection between the server and the clients should treated in a separated thread. So, there is no problem

Answer (score 1):

I have not yet found an easy way to see if an object is still in a usable state.  Each object makes its own rules.

In your specific case with ServerSocket I would try one of two different things:

- Run netstat or some other utility to see what the OS thinks that the socket is doing.  If the OS doesn't think it is listening, then something happened.
  or
- Write a test program that will throw the exception and see what it does.  I do this all the time (especially with proprietary software).  It would be harder in the ServerSocket case you picked, since all of the scenarios I can think of (e.g. address in use, insufficient privileges, etc.) would never result in an object being still valid.

Comment: Well, these solutions are too platform-dependent. I have Linux at home at Windows 7 at the office, what if there are differences?

Comment: You might need to consider that in your real program too.

Comment: Another idea: Connect to the `ServerSocket` yourself and see f it works.

Answer (score 1):

> But SocketTimeoutException is not the only thing that accept() may throw. What does all the other exceptions mean?

According to the [javadoc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/ServerSocket.html#accept%28%29), the declared exceptions are `IOException`, `SecurityException`, `SocketTimeoutException` and `IllegalBlockingModeException`.  The `SecurityException` and `IllegalBlockingModeException` only occur in specific contexts and you should not attempt to catch and handle them.  (They are not problems you want to try to recover from!)  The `IOException` case occurs when "some other I/O error" occurs.  The javadoc does not specify what those I/O errors might be, but possibilities *might* include such things as:

- the address to which you have bound is no longer valid
- a transport protocol error has occurred
- some error (resource issue, bug ...) occurred in the OS protocol stack

(The fact that the javadoc doesn't say which `IOException` subclasses might be thrown is a hint that you shouldn't try to do clever things to try to recover.   If you do, your code is likely to be platform dependent.)

> If I wrap call to accept() with 2 catch clauses: for SocketTimeoutException and IOException, can I still safely use the related ServerSocket instance after I got into IOException clause?

Yes and no.  It is safe in the sense that you won't put your application into a worse state than it is already in.  On the other hand, there is no guarantee that the next `accept` call won't fail with the same problem.

If your application is intended to run as an unattended server, I don't think you have much choice but to log the `IOException` and try again ... hoping that the problem is transient.

Answer (score 0):

You can find your answer to the javadoc of `setsoTimeout`, it says :

> Enable/disable SO_TIMEOUT with the specified timeout, in milliseconds. With this option set to a non-zero timeout, a call to accept() for this ServerSocket will block for only this amount of time. If the timeout expires, a java.net.SocketTimeoutException is raised, though the ServerSocket is still valid. The option must be enabled prior to entering the blocking operation to have effect. The timeout must be > 0. A timeout of zero is interpreted as an infinite timeout.

Comment: It's only related with the `SocketTimeoutException`. What about others?